# 'Error=2, No such file or directory' error in android adb shell

Tags: android

Save the file on the web to cacheDir and run it as follows.

'error=2, No such file or directory' error occurs

If you go to the folder in the terminal, the file is there and the permissions are OK.

What is the problem?

```
adb install -r /data/user/0/pakagename/cache/app.apk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adb install` will install files in your local PC.
You should use:

```
# enter shell on the device
adb shell
# execute in device
pm install /data/user/0/pakagename/cache/app.apk
```

Or use one command:

```
adb shell pm install /data/user/0/pakagename/cache/app.apk
```